# Is there Sport accent characters in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Does anyone know how to sport accent characters in ROKU?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roku does support accented characters, just make sure you are using a font that supports multiple languages.
[Google's Noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) is a great choice.

Comment: Hello, I tried to use ↶ this symbol in Label Title. But It's not supported, Displayed Cross sign. I so many ways tried to found any way to display Reload sign in the text without the image. But no luck. you know any way to support this kind of thing.